# Disable All Child Loggers

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

So I have a python script I am running that uses `logging` with a top-level logger that is simply:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And then that script imports a bunch of other stuff that also uses `logging` and as a result I get a ton of output because these other scripts also log at the `DEBUG` level. I would like to be able to only get `logging` output from my top-level logger and not from any of the child loggers from the modules.

Is there a way I can disable all child loggers without having to manually name and configure each one?

Answer (score -1):

For better control of your logging, don't use the root logger as a default to log to - just use it for the handlers (so that all child loggers inherit the handlers added to the root logger), and leave its level at `WARNING` (the default). In all modules, log to a logger obtained by doing

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

In your `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, set levels on specific loggers where you want a level other than `WARNING`.